# AWS+OpsWorks: How to enable detailed monitoring for EC2 instance with OpsWorks

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-opsworks

Is there a way to enable detailed monitoring for AWS EC2 instance using OpsWorks? I know this can be done with cloud formation but I'm using OpsWorks.

For the person who down voted. I did google and searched stackoverflow for a solution. I spent over two weeks searching and testing this before posting this question on stackoverlow. This is my first time using stackoverflow for asking a question and did not realize I had to add such information.

Answer (score 0):

OpsWork Detailed Monitoring is Enabled By Default.

Refer:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/ops-metricscollected.html

Hope It Helps.. :)

Comment: Thanks. Given this I'm seeing my EC2 instance are setup with "Basic monitoring" after being created with OpsWorks. Which then requires me to click on the "Enable Detailed Monitoring" in the EC2 instance console. Which does not work as I need this to be done in an automated way.

Answer (score 0):

Opsworks by default doesn't enable detailed monitoring. You can achieve the same using chef recipes as part of setup

https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/aws#instance_monitoringrb